# Delete repeated pairs in a string

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string `S='BDBCFBCFABDDEABCCDGAEAABCEAAHF'`. The string `S` is combined by many pairs respectively such as : `'BD'`, `'BC'`, `'FB'`,...,`'HF'`.

How can I delete all of the repeated pairs in this string? I would like to delete the pairs which has the same characters as well such as `'AA'`,`'BB'`,...,`'ZZ'`

The output should be:

```
Out = 'BDBCFBCFABEABCCDGAEACEHF'
```

Comment: According to your description, I think `out = 'BDBCFBCFABEABDGAEEHF'`.  Is it correct? If you follow the steps once more, I think `EE` will be deleted too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your restrictions maybe you're after:

```
U = unique(reshape(S,[],2),'rows','stable')
```

And from there you can delete rows of double letters like:

```
out = U(U(:,1)~=U(:,2),:)
```

Comment: Your output will be pairs in line by line. How to put all pairs in one line ?How to make the output like this : Out = 'BDBCFBCFABEABCCDGAEACEHF'